# Qt how force the releasing of mouse

Tags: qt, mouse, pressed

On event I would like force to release the mouse if it's pressed.
I thought to use QApplication but I don't manage.
How does it possible ?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: I have buttons with slot on pressed and released event. I would like, when a modal popup is shown and if the user is pressing the mouse, the click must be release to execute the slot on released event

Comment: I assume your problem is the fact that the code you have under release of the mouse is not getting called because the modal dialog takes over and when it's closed, the mouse has already been released? If so, can't you assume the release has occurred when the dialog closes and just call whatever functions you would normally do in the release? Or is the problem more complex?

Comment: If a modal dialog is shown, released even is never emit. I have some functions called on released event, so it's a little complex. I wanted to be generic, but I think it isn't possible so I will call functions witch are called on released event. Thanks